# How to write a multi-select input tag without plugin

Tags: javascript, json

I had already searched multiple site but all of them is using plugin,
I want to make a input tag to do multi select
[which is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtqCr.png), without using third party plugin is that possible 
 Just using pure javascript or some JQUERY in case is impossible to write that function.

Comment: All of the third party plugins are using JavaScript to create those inputs. They're not "native" in browsers, the closest you will get is a `select` with the `multiple` attribute. I'd suggest finding a lightweight plugin/library or trying some code for yourself. If you have trouble coding it, post what you have tried here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something to get you going:

```js
function addTag(tag) {
  if(tag.value==undefined) return;
  var tags=document.getElementById("tags");
  var span=document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent=tag.value;
  tag.value="";
  span.style.backgroundColor="whitesmoke";
  span.style.margin="2px";
  span.style.padding="2px";
  span.setAttribute("onclick", "this.remove()");
  tags.append(span);
}
```

```html
<div id="line" style="border:1px solid blue;padding:2px;">
  <span id="tags"></span>
  <input id="tag" onchange="addTag(this)">
</div>
```

This code will add anything entered in input as a tag in tags.
Clicking the tag will remove it.

Comment: Thanks, Fenr1, for the accept!
Up-voted as well?
Styling is up to you... :)